# Chromebook Google Drive Folder Sync

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

I'm rocking a Chromebook HP 11 and loving it so far but there's something I can't figure out. I have a folder in Google Drive that contains lots and lots of little `.md` markdown files and I'm going to be in a cabin in the woods for a week. I want to pull them all offline and then have them sync when I find an internet connection later.

The only sync I can find is the 'offline docs' extension which seems to only work on google document types. There's also the "make available offline" function but that seems to be only on a file-by-file basis.

Is there any way to have a folder with many tiny files download, be available offline and then sync automatically without having to install crouton?